# Best way to bind form array using patchValue in Angular 12 reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, formarray

I am getting data in different format but after using 'split' finally I got the proper value in response. Now the console shows the response data as below:

```
0:{ name: 'dev', label: 'actor' },
1:{ name: 'madhu', label: 'actress' },
 ......
```

Now I want to patch these data in my formArray

I have created one demo for better understanding..

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ke1d7b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push formGroup into the formArray, as below. Anytime you want to add data, you can push into the array ( you can use the extension you made to get the form control 'credentials')

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      credentials: this.fb.array(this.getData()),
    });
  }

  getData(): FormGroup[] {
    return this.data.map(d => this.fb.group({
      name: d.name,
      label: d.label,
    }))
  }
```

Comment: in demo it is working but when I try to use this code in real application it shows an error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: my bad, i get data on click event in real app not oninit!

Comment: Now its working fine! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `patchvalue()` as defined in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#patchValue)

```
// Get the data from the service or a placeholder defined here
const dataFromService: Array<{name: string; label: string}> = [
  { name: 'dev', label: 'actor' },
  { name: 'madhu', label: 'actress' }
];
// patch the form array with your data
// as long as your data conforms to the names of the FormControls in your formArray, patchValue works
form.patchValue(dataFromService);
```

Comment: I tried to use your code but nothing happens! also No errors!

Comment: I guess its ok if  I use : const dataFromService: Array<{name: string; label: string}> = this.data

form.patchValue({id: this.id, reference: dataFromService })

Comment: I agree with you @Edward that using patchValue() would be a good practice! Please give me some idea to get rid of this issue.. if possible.